# C++ Code Creating Empty HDF5 File Instead of Dataset

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have the following code in my class to create a HDF5 file with a matrix of zeros. However, it creates an empty hdf5 file with no datasets at all. How do I write the dataset to the file?

```
#include <H5Cpp.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

H5::H5File file("test_save.hdf5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
hsize_t dims[2] {10, 5};


std::cout << dims[0] << " " << dims[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << data_set_name << std::endl;
H5::DataSpace dataspace(2, dims);

auto dataset = file.createDataSet("test_dataset", H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE, dataspace);
Eigen::MatrixXd temp(10, 5);
temp.setZero();
dataset.write(temp.data(), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);

dataset.close();
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is done with the H5Cpp library, but with [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) it can be solved as follows (please note that the data written will be zeroes since you call `temp.setZero();`):

```
#include <HDFql.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

HDFql::execute("CREATE TRUNCATE AND USE FILE test_save.hdf5");

HDFql::execute("CREATE DATASET test_dataset AS DOUBLE(10, 5)")

Eigen::MatrixXd temp(10, 5);
temp.setZero();

sprintf(script, "INSERT INTO test_dataset VALUES FROM MEMORY %d", HDFql::variableTransientRegister(temp.data()));

HDFql::execute(script);
```